# Deactivate button inside ScrollViewer when scrolling is activate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scroll, touch

My problem is the following. When i m scrolling if my finger touch up on a button the command will be called. How is the best way with MVVM architecture to stop this and deactivate button if the user scroll and conversely.

```
<ScrollViewer  PanningMode="Both" PanningDeceleration="0.001" PanningRatio="2">
        <Grid>
            <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding ListGstDescriptors}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Button  Command="{StaticResource ChangeSavedViewCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding GstDescriptorAcDescriptor}"/>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Set the behavior of CanExecute to false when your scroll moves [This Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM) can help you more in understanding commands

Comment: Yes it was what i want to do but how know on my function canexecute that the scroll moves is activate ? On ScrollViewer nothing goes to true when scroll moves.

Comment: Just Handle ScrollChanged  event this will fire only when scroll moves, so you can have a boolean field to set or directly set CanExecute in the handler

Comment: May be i m wrong but like this, i don't know when the scrolling has finish to set CanExecute at true.